# how to get tcp/udp/socket statistics of a container inside it which is based on cgroup such as docker?

Tags: sockets, docker, snmp, netstat

how to get tcp/udp/socket statistics of a container inside it which is based on cgroup such as docker?

the data from those files are not right.

```
/proc/net/sockstat
/proc/net/snmp
/proc/net/netstat
```